# How to assign column header/name pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe column looks like below:

```
   0
```

0  9.03

1  10.17

2  11.18

How do I assign a column name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To rename column `0` to `foo`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[9.03], [10.17], [11.18]])
df.rename(columns={0: "foo"}, inplace=True)
df
# =>      foo
#    0   9.03
#    1  10.17
#    2  11.18
```